# Linear Congruent Generator for unique, non-repeating random number for Postgresql in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Can I use LCG, aka Linear Congruent Generator, to give my staff a **9-digit, unique but non-repeating** work ID.

The algorithm should use `BSD rand()` formula with initial seed(state 0) is 111,111,111 but change `mod 2^31` to `mod 999,999,937`:

[image: rand]

But do I have to always retrieve the `work ID` from last added staff to calculate next one?

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I use LCG, aka Linear Congruent Generator, to give my staff a 9-digit, unique but non-repeating work ID.

It depends on how you use it.

If you want to generate a work ID per request, then no, you can't, because

> LCGs are not suitable for parallel programming. Multiple threads may access the currently stored state simultaneously causing a race condition. In implementations which use same initialization for different threads, equal sequences of random numbers may occur on simultaneously executing threads. Random number generators, particularly for parallel computers, should not be trusted.

(See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#Advantages_and_disadvantages_of_LCGs))

But you can pre-generate a bunch of work IDs, and for each employee, just assign the first unused one to him/her.

For example, you can pre-generate work IDs using `db/seed.rb` (suppose you have an AR model `WorkId`)

**db/seed.rb**

```
total_work_ids = 10_000  # based on how many potential employees
state = 111_111_111      # the seed

total_work_ids.times do
  state = (1_103_515_245 * state + 12345) % 999_999_937
  WorkId.create(value: '%09d' % state)
end
```

### UPDATE

Using database to store work IDs is may still have race conditions, since every time a new work ID is acquired, one query (`SELECT id, value FROM work_ids WHERE used = 0 LIMIT 1`) and one update (`UPDATE work_ids SET used = 1 WHERE id = ?`) is needed, it's not atomic.

I think the best solution is to implement an external service outside Rails application, which serves work IDs in a first-in-first-out manner. This service should be fast because it is accessed by all the Rails threads/processes and blocks them.

I think a [redis set](http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro#sets) is a good place to store those unused work ids because it ensures uniqueness of the elements in it, and its `spop` is atomic.

Comment: Is `WorkId` in the answer a new table?

Comment: Yes, it is. But the answer itself is not optimal. You may encounter race conditions when acquiring work id from database because it requires at least one query and one update. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I will definitely check out `redis set`, I think that is exactly what I am looking for: a persistent store for last value.